# Queue in which values can be removed that aren't on top

Tags: stack, queue, pygame, playing-cards

I'm creating a computerised version of the card game "spit" using pygame for a project I'm working on. In Spit, the player has 5 hand piles, storing up to 5 cards, with the top card face up and the rest face down. When a card is removed from a card pile and place on a game pile, I want the remaining values of the hand pile to "move up" so that the second value in the list is now the first one.

For this, I planned on using a queue, but there is a problem with that.
In the game, when a hand pile is empty, you can take a face down card from another hand pile, flip it, and place it in the empty hand pile so that there are no more empty hand piles. This is called stockpiling.

And here's my problem, that is not possible in a queue. Is there a work around this? Or another form stack in which I can use to replace this?
Thank you for your time and I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like lists could do the job here. You can represent each hand stack by a list with the index 0 being the downmost card. You can then use the list.pop() method to get and remove the last card (visible one) of the list when it's played on the board.

For the stockpiling, if I understand correctly, you can get any card in any stack (except the topmost one, which is visible), take it out and put it on top of the empty stack (which will be an empty list). You can do that with:

```
firstList[0] = chosenCard    #Get the chosen card from the first pile
del firstList[0]             #Delete the downmost card. The new list will have element 
                             #firstList[0] equal to the old firstList[1], like a stack
secondList.append(chosenCard) #Add the card to the end of the list (top of the stack)
```